# kivy python program closes immediately on launch on android

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am trying to run following simple python code on android using kivy-launcher:

```
# from: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

The `android.txt` file is simple:

```
title=TestApp
author=ABC
orientation=landscape
```

It runs all right on desktop where a window opens with text `Hello world` centered on it. The window remains open till it is closed by clicking `x` button on right upper corner.

However, on selecting it on phone, the program launch screen appears and then it just finishes and I am back to phone's home screen.

Where is the problem and how can this be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to check is whether you are indeed using Kivy version 1.0.6 (most likely not).  If you are not, make sure you replace it with what the Kivy Launcher uses (looks like the latest Kivy Launcher implements version 1.9.1).  Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with the script as posted.  Also, the Python file must be saved as main.py for the Launcher to run it.  Basically, make sure you follow the directions under "Packaging your application for the Kivy Launcher" from this page: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html.  If it still doesn't work, try reinstalling the Kivy Launcher on your Android device, and then add your main.py and android.txt again.

Keep in mind that the Kivy Launcher is only for very basic testing.  Beyond that, you will need to start using a tool like Buildozer to compile your own APK.  In my own experience it was a painful process to begin using Buildozer, but it was worthwhile. Have fun!

Comment: The python code file was not named `main.py`. Correcting the name worked.

Comment: Why `kivy-launcher` is not recommended for regular use?

Comment: The Kivy Launcher is fine for testing simple applications, but in order to deploy an app on the app store, or to develop an app with more than the basic dependencies, you will need to compile it into an APK.  Also, it's possible to retrieve a debug report from an APK, which may not be possible with the Kivy Launcher.